# Java JPA Entities Optimal Queries for GUIs

Tags: jpa, join, jtable

Assume e.g. we have 2 entities :

```
CUSTOMER (cust_ID, Name, Surname)
PRODUCT (prod_ID, Description)
```

related "many-to-many" via a 3rd entity PURCHASE (purch_ID, cust_ID, prod_ID, dateOfPurchase).

I want to retrieve for example all products purchased by a **specific customer** and display them in a JTable with columns

prod_ID  purch_ID  (Product) Description DateOfPurchase

To my understanding I need to implement a Query Joining CUSTOMER, PRODUCT and PURCHASE tables, WHERE customer="My Customer", and then bind this query-list to the table...

Is there a more efficient way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply put - no. The data needed are distributed in those three tables and with this model there is no way around joining those three tables.

But this is a common use case, with database indexes set up correctly there shouldn't be any significant performance impact.